# What is causing strange horizontal "flare" on all my photos regardless of lens and/or POV?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, artifacts, lens-flare, ghosting

Suddenly on (almost) all photos I have a strange light band in the middle, regardless of lens and or angle on which I shoot the photos. The camera is an old Canon 1Ds Mk II and AFIAS the line of light appears when I shoot at shutter speeds faster than approx. 1/60 secs.

Here are some test photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is bad? Can I fix it?

TIA for your feedback.

Comment: It does look like a shutter problem.  You have my sympathy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a shutter malfunction (which fits with it only appearing at certain shutter speeds). The shutter is made of a series of metal blades, it looks like one of these blades is misaligned, which is exposing that part of the sensor for longer than it should be, hence the bright area.

You can have the shutter replaced at a Canon service centre.